# Decoding RTP payload as H264 using wireshark

Tags: h.264, wireshark, rtsp, rtp

I am streaming a RTSP video from vlc on windows to ipad app. And I capture packets in wireshark. I can see RTP packets in wireshark and also the RTP header fields like payload type, timestamp, sequence number. My question is, is it possible to decode the RTP payload as H264 NAL units. Currently I can only see the bytes in payload.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to configure Wireshark to understand that the RTP dynamic payload type maps to H264.

To do this, use the menu; Edit->Preferences->Protocols->H264

Set H264 dynamic payload types to the value shown in the RTP decode for the payload type.

Comment: Thanks for reply, rtp payload type is 14, and i set it in Edit->Preferences->Protocols->H264, but getting the same binary value in payload.

Comment: That payload type is not H264, the setting I gave only works for the dynamic types. See here for a list of payload types: http://www.iana.org/assignments/rtp-parameters/rtp-parameters.xhtml

Comment: Thanks, now i am getting payload type 96 and now i can decode payload in wireshark. Thanks for the help.