# how to decode AVTP h264 packets in wireshark

Tags: h.264, decoding, codec, rtp

I got a AVTP packet data from vehicle`s side mirror camera.
protocol is H264(AKA codec) and transported by FU-A.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un8qw.png)

**I want to decode these data to stream.** Before, I refered [rtp_h264_extractor.lua](https://github.com/hissinger/wireshark-rtp-h264-extractor/blob/master/rtp_h264_extractor.lua), but it does not work well.

My question is how to combine my data for decoding.

First, there are SPS, PPS, I-Slice in wireshark. but, no start code(\x00 \x00 \x00 \x01). Just type code(\x67, \x68, \x65).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1iGG.png)
\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 is h264 timestamp, not start code.
Is it ok just add start code by myself?

Second, Unkown(not indicate I-slice) packets have start code + I-slice type code.

Third, SPS and PPS are separated very far. PPS is next to SPS, but my data`s SPS packet number is 10, PPS is 122. I-Slice start packet and I-Slice end packet is located between SPS and PPS.
Unkown I-Slice packets(Second) are located between SPS and PPS too.

Let me know Some tips for combine my data.

Thanks a lot.

I tried parsing SPS, PPS, I-Slice in wireshark by scapy, and using ffmpeg. But does not work.

Under tries are not work too.

1. [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164442/decoding-rtp-payload-as-h264-using-wireshark)

Comment: Have u seen this Post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362239/rtp-depacketization